# Angular Web App & Web API with Windows Authentication for Intranet users

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication

I have intranet web application developed using pure angular and the API app is web api 2

i want to give the windows authentication for the web application and web api

But the angular App i cannot have the server side code to get the useridentity

how to implement that.